# Domain of operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Let be $\lambda\in C^{*}$. Consider the following operator:

$ T_{\lambda}=-\Delta_{R^{2}}++\frac{\lambda^{2} }{4} (x^{2}+y^{2})+i\lambda N$,

where

$N=(x \frac{d }{dy} -y \frac{d }{dx})$      ,

with domain $D=\{u\in L^{2}(R^{2}), T_{\lambda}\in L^{2}(R^{2})\}$

I want  to prove $D=\{u\in L^{2}(R^{2}):   \Delta_{R^{2}}u\in L^{2}(R^{2}),(x^{2}+y^{2})u\in L^{2}(R^{2}),N u\in L^{2}(R^{2}) \}$

Would you know some litterature reference for this problem that I could read ?

Thanks!